# Altium toolbar 'design'

Tags: altium

Can't find the 'design' menu on the toolbar anywhere. I am looking for the 'update template' form.

I am still learning altium so I have no clue what I am missing. I opened an existing project and want to update the sheet information section.

Comment: Nevermind.. Was using the viewer... blame it on the Monday. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

To update Sheet information:

1. Open your Schematic sheet
2. Click right click within the sheet
3. Go to Options >> Document Options

You can edit all sheet parameters from here

Comment: Not exactly what I needed. I really did want to update the template not adjust any sheet parameters. That's step two. Thanks for the reply though :) much appreciated.